# Mule: What are the problems of having metadata in DW?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Is it pushed to git? Deployed? Will it give some performance issues?

What are the challenges and why is it considered a best practice to not have metadata in DW?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by metadata? Is it Studio metadata? Is it type annotations on DataWeave code? Also what sources you have regarding it as a best practice?

Comment: In transform message - there are input and output panes. In the start it contains "Payload: Unknown Define Metadata". Once we click, it takes us to window where we can choose format - xml, json, csv etc.. I am analysing the pro/cons of that "set metadata"

Comment: @BharathKesavan there are no pros/cons per se other than facilitating your development without your server running (aka static time, aka design time).  Here start reading these pages: https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.4/datasense-concept and https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.4/metadata-editor-concept, there are probably more pages but these are a good start.  One aspect you need to know is that setting metadata is ONLY used while you are in Studio, the Mule Runtime couldn't care less about the things you do to facilitate development at static time.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen it considered 'Best Practice' to not have metadata in your project. The problem currently, especially in AnyPoint Studio 7+ is that is has trouble determining metadata automatically.

For instance, if you have an encryption key and environment placeholders (i.e app.key, app.env), AnyPoint studio will not be able to resolve metadata, even if you set it for a processor explicitly, without providing the value for each of those placeholders in a Global Property configuration. Because of workarounds like this, most mule devs that I'm aware of use the Docker Image [DataWeave Playground](https://hub.docker.com/r/machaval/dw-playground/) to generate dwl scripts and transfer them their mule projects.